# How to load a mesh quietly?

Tags: mesh, scripting

I am using Python script to load a mesh from `.obj` format file. It output some information when it loading. I want to disable the output. How can I do?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty workaround : Navigate to your blender installation folder. Open "2.**/scripts/addons/io_scene_obj" folder and open *import_obj.py* in your favorite text editor.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to bring in the Search & Replace tool. Replace `print(` by `if False: print(` for all occurences in file. This will neutralize all outputs to the console.

[image]

You'll have to do it again every time you update Blender.

Comment: I noticed afterwards that it was for a script. If you're going to distribute it, this answer won't help one bit and you should indeed follow the suggested duplicate.